# Find a line of regression with the following points

Tags: statistics, systems-of-equations, regression

Find a line of regression in the form
\begin{align}
y &= \frac{c}{1+a e^{-b(x)}} \\[4mm]
\end{align}

with the points
$(69.99, 44), (84.71, 54), (93.66, 60), (116.36, 74)$

I can easily find the answer using a calculator but I need to know if it's possible by hand, and if so, what the steps are. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$y(x)=\frac{c}{a e^{-b(x)}}$$
$$\begin{cases}
\ln(44) \simeq \ln(\frac{c}{a})+69.99\:b \\
\ln(60) \simeq \ln(\frac{c}{a})+93.66\:b\\
\ln(74) \simeq \ln(\frac{c}{a})+116.36\:b
\end{cases} \qquad\text{Let}\quad \frac{c}{a}=e^A$$
Without specification about the expected kind of regression and about criteria of fiting, an example of solution (among many):

For example. Linear regression in order to compute $A$ and $b$ :
$$y=A+b\,x\qquad
\text{Three points}\quad\begin{cases}
y_1=\ln(44)\quad,\quad x_1=69.99 \\
y_2=\ln(60)\quad,\quad x_2=93.66\\
y_3=\ln(74)\quad,\quad x_3=116.36
\end{cases}\quad\;\quad$$

IN ADDITION  after you modify the question :

There is one point more. Thus an equation more $y_4\simeq A+b\,x_4$ :
$$y_4=\ln(54)\quad,\quad x_4=84.71$$
This changes nothing in the example of linear regression. Of course the numerical results for $A$ and $b$ will be slightly different.

Comment: I clarified the question- originally the problem was to find the line of regression from a series of points and I thought three equations, three unknowns was the best way to go about this.

Comment: In fact you have not three unknowns but only two. The parameters in the chosen function must be independant. If not they are infinity many solutions. In your function $y= \frac{c}{a e^{-b(x)}}$ the parameters $a$ and $c$ are not independant. Replace them by only one parameter ( In other words simplify the fraction).

Comment: Made a mistake when typing this in, so sorry. It's actually 1 + ae not just ae

Comment: This mistake changes a lot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The equation in the quest was changed, consequently my answer becomes almost obsolete. The hint to [LS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methode_der_kleinsten_Quadrate) remains valid.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the LS method. Unfortunately I typed this in wrong it's actually 1 + ae in the denominator and not just ae.

Comment: Nice :) but then I'd like to know what calculator u used and what it returned as result for a, b, and c.

Comment: TI-84 Plus, just entered data set and clicked line of regression > logistical. Got a = 8.55, b = 0.0246 and c = 103.357

Comment: LOL! Could it be you just test all options of your new calculator, the given data is _not_ the result of measuring? It smells fishy that your four points show in linear regression a correlation of $r^2=0.9992$ -- I feel bamboozled, investigated some time to show LS method for a formula that was wrong -- not so funny me think.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been changed so that the answer becomes very different. A distinc answer is given below in order to avoid confusion with the previous answer.

Your first equation was : $\quad y = \frac{c}{a e^{-b(x)}}\quad$. Your new equation is :
$$y = \frac{c}{1+a e^{-b(x)}} $$
For the first equation a simple linear regression $Y=A+b\,x$ was sufficient in considering $Y=\ln(y)$.

For the second equation the problem is very different because one cannot linearise with $Y=\ln(y)$ as before. The regression is non longer linear but is non-linear.

The usual way for non-linear regression is to use iterative method of calculus starting from "guessed" values of the parameters. Many softwares are available to do it.

When no particular criteria of fitting is required (This is the case in the present wording of the question) a more direct method (not iterative) can be proposed. Eventually the numerical calculus could be done by hand but this would be rather boring because the matix inversion.

METHOD DESCRIPTION :

For explanations about the general principle see
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

[image]

NUMERICAL CALCULUS :

[image]

RESULT :

[image]

If a particular criteria of fitting is required nonlinear regression is necessary. Use any software for nonlinear regression. If difficulies appear with the iteratve process take the values found above as good initial values.

For comparison : With a required criteria of fitting LMSE (for example) the result from a nonlinear regression software is : $a=8.55143534$ ; $b=0.0263881773$ ; $c=103.35740847$ . With another criteria of fitting the result would be slightly different. All these small differences are indistinguishable on the drawing of the curve.

NOTE : The logistic curve is badly defined with only four points. As a consequence the result can be more or less different depending on the method of fitting and/or the method of calculus.

Comment: Bravo ! Bien impressionnant :)
@ell got with his TI-84 a = 8.55, b = 0.0246 and c = 103.357 -- I speculate the _minuscule_ deviations result from the fact that the four points actually "sit" on a straight line (simple sample data, calculated not measured). Linear regression shows a correlation of $r^2=0.9992$.

Comment: The link for the explanations about the general principle, fr.scribd..., is behind a paywall. Even advertised as _"30 days free"_ I'm urged to enter my credit card data. That is not the kind of "free" I like. So could you please be so kind and show the source of your marvelous solution, something else but your own book.

Comment: @m-stgt. I am very surprised This is the first time that someone say that "scribd" asks for paying to read one of my documents. They are several of my papers on this site which are read several times each day. As far as I know the readings are always free. Also I am surprized that you wrote fr.sribd . Why fr.? Isn't it a faked website ? Try again with https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales or with http://www.scribd.com/JJacquelin/documents/ . Please make me known if you get a free connection.

Comment: @m-stgt. Don't click on the button "Lisez gratuitement pendant 30 jours". Simply click on the icon of "Regressions et equations integrales" to open the document.

Comment: @m-stgt. A small part of this paper was translated and is available on : https://scikit-guess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendices/reei/translation.html .

Comment: @ Jacquelin --TY very much, the mistakes are completely on my side, i) I tryed to _download_ your paper but I may read it _online only_, and ii) either my x86 laptop or my browser are not apt to function properly with scribd.com, on an other machine it works.  
I'm highly interested in the derivation of the equations you use, just because I done it myself for orthogonal linear regression (something I started as student and finished now decades later _with_ a CAS)-- nothing special compared to your paper.

Comment: @ Jacquelin -- Nice paper, alas, no references, all know-how is _god-given_, any know-why remains vague.

Comment: @m-stgt. I have no reference about this method. If you like it take it as god-given.

Comment: @m-stgt. I made a few bibliographic search about references of this method of fitting (Not a deep search, only a quick search). Nothing found except my own publication. Nevertheless the general principle of the method seems so simple and obvious that probably it has been found and applied a long time ago. I cannot say  where it was invented and by whom.